# How to ferment green indigo powder to make it blue

Tags: pigments, soap-making

I have bought indigo powder to color my soaps blue (cold/hot process saponification). Unfortunately I received something which color is closer to match than blue jeans...
After some internet research I found that what I have is unfermented indigo powder, while the blue colorant is made with fermented indigo; very detailed information [here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2018.02196/full).

My question: does someone have a recipe to ferment my green powder to get something blue I can use in my soaps? I found a lot of vat recipes, but that's to dye fabric and I don't think it will work in soaps.

Comment: It seems the green indigo needs to oxidize. Have you tried mixing it with water and dying cloth with this mixture, to see if it oxidizes while drying?

Comment: That article says that blue indigo is made by *oxidation*, while fermentation does the reverse, *reduction*.

Comment: I did not try to dye cloth with it, but it is exposed to air when the soap dry. However the color did not change.

Answer (score 1):

Try mixing the unfermented indigo powder with water in a bowl, and '*beating*' it, using a smaller bowl to scoop it up and pouring it back until the mix turns blue.

Consider adding [lye](https://www.coyuchi.com/the-naturalista/indigo_dyeing/) [NaOH] or [slaked lime](https://thekindcraft.com/the-process-indigo-from-plant-to-paste/) [Ca(OH)2] to help the fermentation process. The effectiveness might depend on how the unfermented powder was produced, though.